# How can I get back the ability to hide lines of code from the Xamarin IDE by clicking on a box in the left had column in the editor?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just updated to the latest Xamarin and now it seems like in my IDE I no longer have the ability to hide the lines of code of a function or the XAML code in the IDE.

I think there is a word for this but I am not sure what the word is.  Has anyone else noticed a change. I have a lot of large files and I want to be able to make it so the methods are hidden in C# and so ranges of from `<Grid>` to `</Grid>` are hidden in XAML. But now I have nothing to click on the left side of the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the feature is called **Code Folding**

in the latest VS Mac, you have to hover over the left side of the text file (near the line numbers) for the folding icons to display

enable/disable folding

```
Preferences --> Text Editor --> General --> Code Folding
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was just not doing the hovering.  I wonder how many other had the same problem where the code folding doesn't appear unless do that.  I prefer it the old way where it was clearly visible all the time.